# Issue with DAO java file being called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to Java spring and currently within the code I am updating there is a UserDetailsDao class I am trying to call in another java file.

```
@Repository public class UserDetailsDao {
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template; //blah blah functions}
```

This is the java file I am trying to call a function I need from the DAO class file to get:

```
public class LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

public final Integer SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 7500;
private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication)
                                    throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    
    String redirectPath = "/";
    
    User u = new User();
    
    //UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao = new UserDetailsDao();
   
   // u = userDetailsDao.getUserDetailedInfo(request.getParameter("username"));
   //gimme my data!
    UserDetailsServiceImpl utest = userDetailsService();
    u = utest.getUserDetails(request.getParameter("username"));
    request.setAttribute("user", u);
    
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectPath);
}
```

}

I tired to call a bean of the service imp file that has this setup working and call functions via here:

```
    @Bean
public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}
```

or

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao;
```

When i debug the logging in portion of the application once I get to the LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler class file that has call to a function within here to get user detailed data of a user the UserDetailsDao  is always null regardless of the various ways that I try to call the DAO class file. This is where I am so confused, in comparison to another file within the code, UserDetailsServiceImpl , that is able to use UserDetailsDao simply by having the at autowired and using that var to call functions within the DAO with no null to the DAO iteslef:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao;
```

in its class file. I have tired reading up the various annotations, looking up similar errors, reading others examples and it doesn't seem to stick to my mind. My guess is it has something to do with the annotations as well as the class file LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler in which I am trying to call the DAO. If someone could point to me what I am doing wrong and have a link of something where I can learn more.

Comment: Have you tried using [constructor injection](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring) instead of `@Autowired`?

Comment: Is the other class that you claim is being able to use `UserDetailsDao` annotated with e.g. `@Service` or `@Component` by any chance? I get the feeling it might be a case of you missing to supply this class with an instance of your DAO, which would otherwise be managed by the IoC container.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand so the other file is called UserDetailsServiceImpl and implements UserDetailsService. Within UserDetailsServiceImpl it has at Autowired
private UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao and within that class are other functions that call userDetailsDao without it being null. That class file does not have at service or at component

Comment: @testItAll how do you instantiate the LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler class?

Comment: @maximus so that is one part i do not understand, the code shows that the only place i see it called is in another class file WebSecurityConfig which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter within the WebSecurityConfig  it has a method:  public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler(){ return new LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler();} then this gets called in  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) that is also within this WebSecurityConfig  file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is not a `Bean` so Spring can't inject another `Bean` into it. In this scenario, you should provide your `UserDetailsDao` bean to the `LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class, like so:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao;

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler(){
        return new LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler(this.userDetailsDao);
    }
}
```

And

```java
public class LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao;

    public LoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler(UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao) {
        this.userDetailsDao = userDetailsDao;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I eventually figured out and ended up moving this under a controller and it is working their just fine